# Is there a way to read tar.gz top lines without uncompression?

Tags: gzip, tar

I have 1000+ `*.tar.gz` files with size `4G+` each. But the only thing that I needed is the top 5 lines of each file. I am wondering whether there is a fast way to read these lines without uncompressing process (it takes 3-5 minutes to uncompress a single file).
My platform is Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is partial gz decompression possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676116/is-partial-gz-decompression-possible)

Comment: I think you can use `split -b X` to take only the first X byes of the file, then decompress

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any faster way.

The issue is that `.tar` file is stream of concatenated original files (with some meta information). `gzip` then adds compression of full archive. Therefore even to just get the list of the files the archive has to be uncompressed first.